# App crashes after button click implementation in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-button

My app contains navigation drawer. And within that there is one item fragment. In that fragment I tried to implement three button click events to open 3 activities. But, whenever I click on the fragment from the navigation drawer the app crashes with nullPointerAcception. After debug it shows issues with the below code containing onClickListener:

```
itemButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent itemIntent=new Intent(getActivity(),ItemsActivity.class);
                startActivity(itemIntent);
            }
        });
```

Here's my fragment code.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class ItemsFragment extends Fragment {

    Button itemButton;
    Button categoryButton;
    Button discountButton;

    public ItemsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        itemButton=(Button) container.findViewById(R.id.items_button);
        categoryButton=(Button) container.findViewById(R.id.category_button);
        discountButton=(Button) container.findViewById(R.id.discount_button);

        itemButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent itemIntent=new Intent(getActivity(),ItemsActivity.class);
                startActivity(itemIntent);
            }
        });

        setHasOptionsMenu(false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_items, container, false);
    }

}
```

// The Logcat error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at com.soumya.possystem.ItemsFragment.onCreateView(ItemsFragment.java:36)
                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1677)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:536)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what is exception?

Comment: Please post the exception stacktrace from logcat.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: I am adding the logcat @Code-Apprentice

Comment: It's a nullPointerException @VivekMishra

Comment: @SoumyaRauth please check the answer . this will resolve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/41720571/1140237

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this for information about fixing NullPointerExceptions.

Comment: Step through the code in the debugger. You will probably find that `itemButton=(Button) container.findViewById(R.id.items_button);` returns `null`. In this case it means that there is no `Button` with the ID `items_button` in the layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before inflating view and created view you are trying to find instance of the controls.and return inflated view in `onCreateView`

Another way is to take the instance(`findviewById`) in `onViewCreated` or `onActivityCreated`

Second issue is you are trying to get control's object from `container` instead of that you need to should take from inflated view.

```
View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_items, container, false);
```

Below i have kept code with changes.

```
import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;


    /**
     * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
     */
    public class ItemsFragment extends Fragment {

        Button itemButton;
        Button categoryButton;
        Button discountButton;

        public ItemsFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_items, container, false);
    //check in place of container here you need to use inflated view (`v`) instance
            itemButton=(Button) v.findViewById(R.id.items_button);
            categoryButton=(Button) v.findViewById(R.id.category_button);
            discountButton=(Button) v.findViewById(R.id.discount_button);

            itemButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent itemIntent=new Intent(getActivity(),ItemsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(itemIntent);
                }
            });

            setHasOptionsMenu(false);
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return v;
        }

    }
```

Comment: can you specify specific code where it is not working

Comment: @jiteshmohite please check the code and comment i've kept where exactly NullPointerException giving crash

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize view as per requirement:
[Create a Fragment Class](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html#Create)

So you have to do
`View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT, container, false);`
and then
`itemButton=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.items_button);`

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class ItemsFragment extends Fragment {

    Button itemButton;
    Button categoryButton;
    Button discountButton;

    public ItemsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /** Inflate rootView of fragment **/
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_items, container, false);

      //replace "container" with "rootView" **/
        itemButton=(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.items_button);
        categoryButton=(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.category_button);
        discountButton=(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.discount_button);

        itemButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent itemIntent=new Intent(getActivity(),ItemsActivity.class);
                startActivity(itemIntent);
            }
        });

        setHasOptionsMenu(false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView; // Return the view object you inflated
    }

}
```

Comment: i'll suggest you to keep explanation for the issue. so user can understand the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_id, container, false);
    itemButton=(Button) container.findViewById(R.id.items_button);
    categoryButton=(Button) container.findViewById(R.id.category_button);
    discountButton=(Button) container.findViewById(R.id.discount_button);
.
.
.

    return rootView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class ItemsFragment extends Fragment {

Button itemButton;
Button categoryButton;
Button discountButton;

public ItemsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_items, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(false);
    return v;
}

 @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
   itemButton=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.items_button);
    categoryButton=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.category_button);
    discountButton=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.discount_button);

    itemButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent itemIntent=new Intent(getActivity(),ItemsActivity.class);
            startActivity(itemIntent);
        }
    });

}
}
```